# Degree of parallelism in Oracle on a table and index

Tags: oracle, database-performance

We have a RAC set up with 4 nodes where certain table has a degree of 1 and instance is 1 and one of the index on that table has DOP as 16 and instance 1.  Just want to know if there is any restriction that table and index should have same DOP? If it's not the case then how it affects the database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Table and index degree of paralelism (DOP) are independent.

The table DOP is used as default in case of table access such as `FULL TABLE SCAN`. Some index access paths can be parallelized, for those the index DOP is used as default.

You situation arise typically if you **create** and index with parallel option. The used DOP is stored for the created index. (May be you need only to *alter* the index DOP to `NOPARALLEL` after the creation).

Here a littele example, creating an index in parallel mode and reeting the DOP afterwards:

```
create index idx on t1(id) parallel 4;

select DEGREE, INSTANCES from user_indexes where index_name = 'IDX';

DEGREE                                   INSTANCES                              
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
4                                        1                                      

alter index idx noparallel;

select DEGREE, INSTANCES from user_indexes where index_name = 'IDX';

DEGREE                                   INSTANCES                              
---------------------------------------- ----------------------------------------
1                                        1
```

In generall you should be carefull with object based default DOP as it is valid for **all** queries. Defining explicit DOP for each query using a `PARALLEL Hint` may be more flexible.

Comment: I asked the developer who had created those Table and the Index, he said he did not explicitlyu mentioned DOP at creation time. DB might have autometically set that value.  Any particular parameter I need to look at?

Comment: @redsoxlost do not relay on propositions, check the system:) I added an example. Create your own index and verify the DOP. An once again IMO the parallel degree is not a feature of a database, instance, table or index but should be set for a particular query.

Answer (score 0):

checked it myself there is no such restriction that a index and its associated table should have same DOP. The only way it affects database is extra load on server due to parallel processes.

Comment: Thanks Sandeep. Would you please share the link where you have checked it.

Comment: :) checked it on my local system